# Python .csv writer putting data on wrong row (Python 3.7) strange formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use BeautifulSoup to extract data from a web page and format that data in a .csv file. I've been pretty successful in getting the data in the page, but I cannot figure out how to format the file correctly.

My problem is that If I have 10 items in the first column (11 rows with the header) the data in the next column starts on my 12th row. The .csv ends up looking staggered (like a staircase), for example:

```
Field1,Field2,Field3
data1,,
data1,,
data1,,
,data2,
,data2,
,data2,
,,data3
,,data3
,,data3
```

Obviously it would be much easier to work with a .csv formatted like:

```
Field1,Field2,Field3
data1,data2,data3
data1,data2,data3
data1,data2,data3
```

My code looks like this:

```
import time
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Time to wait between each item.
t = .010

# Create a csv file to write to.
f = open('filename.csv', 'w')
fieldnames = ('Field1','Field2')
writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = fieldnames, lineterminator = '\n')
writer.writeheader()

# Define target page.
url = 'https://www.example.com'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# Filter useful information from the page.
data_list = soup.find(class_='class0')
data_raw = data_list.find_all(class_='class1')
otherData_raw = otherData_list.find_all(class_='class2')

# Extract [data1] from html.
for data_location in data_raw:
    data_refine = data_location.find_all('a')

    for data_item in data_refine:
        field1 = data_item.contents[0]
        writer.writerow({'Field1':field1})
    time.sleep(t)

# Extract [data2] from html.
for otherData_location in otherData_raw:
    otherData_refine = otherData_location.find_all('a')

    for otherData_item in otherData_refine:
        field2 = otherData_item.contents[0]
        writer.writerow({'Field2':field2})
    time.sleep(t)

f.close()
```

I've tried a few solutions but haven't had any luck. I'm a beginner with Python, so I apologize ahead of time if this is a dumb question. I'd greatly appreciate any help with this issue though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is to gather all of your data before you output anything. If you have multiple pieces of data that you want in a single line, add them all to a list, then write them to a CSV like this:

```
with open('csv.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in csv_data:
        f.write(','.join(line) + '\n')
```

You could of course use the CSV module as well.

If you provide an example page that you would like to scrape as well as the fields of interest, it would help answer your question, it's quite vague as is

Answer (score 0):

The code is writing one cell per row:

```
writer.writerow({'Field1':field1})
```

will write

```
foo,,  # Only Field1 column is populated

writer.writerow({'Field2':field2})
```

will write

```
,foo,  # Only Field2 column is populated
```

Collect all the columns in a row before writing it to the file

```
row = {'Field1': 'foo', 'Field2': 'bar'...}
writer.writerow(row)
```